# Comparable and Nullable constraints on single generic

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, nullable

I want to write an extension method which compares a value against two other values and determines if the value is within the other two. This works for that purpose

```
public static bool IsWithin<T>(this T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return (bool)(value.CompareTo(min) > 0 && value.CompareTo(max) < 0);
}
```

I would also like to extend this method to work on `Nullable<T>`. I would like either boundary condition to be ignored if the value is null. I have tried putting an additional constraint on T, but this is not supported. The following code doesn't compile, but is what I want to achieve.

```
public static bool IsWithinInclusive<T>(this T value, Nullable<T> min, Nullable<T> max) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return (bool)(
        (min.HasValue ? value.CompareTo(min) >= 0 : true) && 
        (max.HasValue ? value.CompareTo(max) <= 0 : true));
}
```

Is it possible write a single method which achieves this?

Comment: You don't need the cast to `bool`, and you can replace `a ? b : true` with `a && b`

Comment: `a && b` is false when `min` is null, I want it to be true. Did I miss something?

Comment: Then you want `!a || b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to constrain `T` to be a `struct` to match the [definition of `Nullable<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,26):

```
public static bool IsWithinInclusive<T>(this T value, Nullable<T> min, Nullable<T> max) where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    return 
        (min.HasValue ? value.CompareTo(min.Value) >= 0 : true) && 
        (max.HasValue ? value.CompareTo(max.Value) <= 0 : true);
}
```

You also need to use `.Value` to get the `T` from the `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

As SLaks answered, the reason `Nullable<T>` (or just `T?`) isn't accepted is because that requires `T` to be a non-nullable value type. You cannot use a single method that covers value and reference types alike: the value types you want to support can't represent `null`, and reference types can't support `T?`, so you can't avoid having two separate methods.

However, you *can* use the exact same function body twice, to make it obvious to a reader that the two overloads do the same thing:

```
public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return (min == null || value.CompareTo((T)min) >= 0)
        && (max == null || value.CompareTo((T)max) <= 0);
}

public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T value, T? min, T? max) where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    return (min == null || value.CompareTo((T)min) >= 0)
        && (max == null || value.CompareTo((T)max) <= 0);
}
```

Comment: Good explanation, I was wondering if I needed two methods. And you got the logic how I wanted it. Thanks.